# Two maps, one with classes and one with no classes. get the sum of one map into the classes of the other

Tags: statistics

I have two maps. One map has some classes and the other one is a raster with no classes. 
To illustrate, the map with the classes: 0-1, 1-2 and 3-4! The other map is a raster with values from 0-1000.

The maps are overlaying. I want to find out the sum of the second map within the classes of the first map, i.e. what is the sum in the first class 0-1 of the values of the second map?

ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: please specify the software that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Zonal Statistics As Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/) Tool. Your classified raster is the zone data and your other raster is the input value raster. Set SUM as your statistics type and specify location of output table.